# Flyway clean removes public/routines and can't migrate afterwards

Tags: postgresql, migration, flyway

When I perform flyway `clean`, it removes everything from my `public` database including all `tables`, but also all `routines`.

The problem is that when I perform my first migration, i'm using `Postgres's` routine `gen_uuid`. Consequently, the migration fails and i'm stuck in a loop.

Is that normal ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, turns out there were a strong coupling between migrations written by the previous team on 2 pg extensions, `pgcrypto` and `unaccent` that was NOT written as migrations by us but by another container in the stack.

The solution is to let `Flyway` manage the creation of these extensions.